# python can load GDAL, but django can't

Tags: django, gdal

I was able to successfully install gdal 1.11 and load it from python shell on my windows 32 bit machine.   I can also verify its success by typing "gdalinfo --version" and getting the correct version info: GDAL 1.11.4, released 2016/01/25

However, when running "python manage.py shell" in django 1.11, I got error 127 'the specified procedure could not be found'.  The error occurred when django called function lgdal = CDLL(lib_path)

I printed out lib_path, it is correct. The same function worked fine in my python shell.

Any idea why loading gdal111.dll would fail in the django environment when it has no problem in the python shell?  Thanks.

Comment: you used `pip install GDAL` ?

Comment: I followed the steps here: http://cartometric.com/blog/2011/10/17/install-gdal-on-windows/